# Updating a UI attribute using DataBinding in Android

Tags: android

I am going through the Android docs on data binding and have tried out the following code:

```
data class User(var firstName: String, var lastName: String)

val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

val user = User("Steve", "Jobs")
binding.user = user

btn_change_firstname.setOnClickListener {
    user.firstName = "John"
}
```

The text view will be updated with the first name and last name. But when I add a button and then change the first name, the text view showing the first name doesn't update. Is there something more I have to do to have that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is the expected behaviour. Either your wrap `firstName`/`lastName` in an `ObservableField` or start using `LiveData`.

Documentation for [ObservableField](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableField) can be found it. Of course, you will have to change your button click listener like

```
btn_change_firstname.setOnClickListener {
    user.firstName.set("John")
}
```

where firstName is declared like `val firstName: ObservableField<String>`.

In this case android will be observing for changes to the field itself

Another way consists in subclassing [BaseObservable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BaseObservable.html) and call [notifyProperyChanged(int field)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BaseObservable.html#notifyPropertyChanged(int)). EG.

```
class User: BaseObservable() {

  var firstName: String = ""
     set(newValue) {
        field = newValue
        notifyProperyChanged(BR.firstName)
     }
}
```

Comment: That's a shame. You would think that if it already bound the textview to a class property, it would be able to update the textview automatically whenever the underlying data class member changed. I hope Google adds that feature.

Comment: another way is to subclass `BaseObservable` and call `notifyPropertyChanged(int fieldId)` after setting the new value

Answer (score 0):

in your layout add

```
<TextView
android:text="@{user.firstName}" />
```

Comment: I already have that. I didn't post it here to keep things short and sweet.

Comment: Then you should try ObservableField or LiveData